# "are not so: but are like" in Psalm 1:4

Tags: hebrew, psalms

What is the basis of the words "are not so: but are like" as translated in the KJV? I'm reading the Bible with strong's numbers and don't see any Hebrew that would indicate that these words should be there.

Answer (score 2):

- לא כן

  - not so
- הרשעים

  - the wicked
- כי אם כמץ

  - as if ash
- אשר תדפנו רוח

  - which wind shall divert it

I think translations have the bad habit of taking the mood away by inserting conjunctions or other whatnots to "help" reader understand the Bible.

> Not so the wicked being as if chaff which wind whisks away.

When translations try to help, they actually take the precision away. By inserting an inverse conjunction not found in the original Hebrew:

> Not so the wicked **but** who are like chaff which  the wind whisks away.

*Rant: Sometimes this bad habit even extend to inserting whole phrases, hence introducing doctrine not found in the Hebrew of the Bible.*

Comment: Should translators introduce phrases into their translations which would introduce doctrine not found in the original Hebrew? http://rameneutics.avishegnath.net/2014/03/does-bible-forbid-gay-sex.html

Comment: So if I wanted to paraphrase in less archaic sounding, but KJV similar English holding true to the original Hebrew, what would you think of, "The wicked *are* not so, being like chaff which *the* wind whisks away"? Would you make any changes?

Comment: I am sticking to "*Not so the wicked being as if chaff which wind whisks away.*" Is it too archaic? The structure is {Not of-such-manner {the wicked-ones = {subjunctive-allegory-to {chaff which wind aversely-removes} }}}.

Comment: Understanding the meaning of [דפן / DFN] is the root to understanding this verse. When farmers harvest grain, after threshing the stalks, they would bounce the grain in the wind, and the wind separates the chaff from the grain. [דפן / DFN] means separate, segregate.

Comment: The *evil* is not "BUT like chaff", they are like the chaff. They exist as part of natural production of what is good. But then we can take available measures to separate them from what we need, and they are blown away. They are part of the environment. All things work not just for the good of those who love G'd, but for the complete framework of creation.